# Visual Studio generating new user secrets file even though one is given in assembly attribute

Tags: .net, visual-studio, configuration

Basically title. I have the following files:

Directory.Build.props

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
        <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
        <IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>false</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

.csproj file (shortened for readability)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <RootNamespace>MyProject.MyApp</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>MyProject.MyApp</AssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="..\..\AssemblyInfo.Solution.cs" Link="Properties\AssemblyInfo.Solution.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="xxx" />
        <PackageReference Include="xxx" />
        <PackageReference Include="xxx" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Application\Application.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <InternalsVisibleTo Include="MyProject.MyAppde.IntegrationTests" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

AssemblyInfo.Project.cs (unique to each project)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets;

[assembly: UserSecretsId("3867c5c2-50b2-4e1a-a53b-c6488418344c")]
```

AssemblyInfo.Solution.cs (shared between projects)

```
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.1.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("2.1")]
```

When I run this, .Net picks up all the values from the secrets file defined in `AssemblyInfo.Project.cs`. However, when I right-click my project and click on `Manage User Secrets`, VS creates a new file and puts the following line in the `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <UserSecretsId="xxxxxx" />
</PropertyGroup>
```

I tried putting the assembly attribute from the `AssemblyInfo.Project.cs` file into the `Program.cs` file, this yielded the same result. Using the same GUID and putting it into the `.csproj` file so VS won't generate a new one worked though.

Strangely enough, only putting the attribute into the `.csproj` file will make VS open the correct secrets file, but it is not enough to load these values into the configuration pipeline. I need to put the attribute also in `AssemblyInfo.Project.cs`.

So summarized:

Putting attribute only in `AssemblyInfo.Project.cs` -> Will load correct values into config pipeline. Will make VS generate a new one when right clicking the project and clicking `Manage User Secrets`.

Putting attribute only in `.csproj` file -> Will not load correct values into config pipeline. Will make VS open the correct one when right clicking the project and clicking `Manage User Secrets`.

Putting attribute in both `.csproj` and `AssemblyInfo.Project.cs` -> only way to get it working both ways

I reckon this is because of the stuff I have in my 'Directory.Build.props' file. Yet it worked when I was still on .Net 7, only after upgrading to 8 did the problem occur.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue. The point is that you set `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>` tp `false`.

.NET CLI and VS use the `<UserSecretsId>` tag in the project file to identify if a user secret is already provided for the project. They do not check for code in your project, so doesn't consider the `[assembly: UserSecretsId("...")]`.

At runtime however, the secrets are read from the folder in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<user secrets id>` where the id was retrieved by the  `[assembly: UserSecretsId("...")]` attribute of the assembly.

Normally, when `GenerateAssemblyInfo` is not specified, or is `true`, the attribute is automatically added to the assembly in the pre-compilation phase.

Since you manually added the `UserSecretsIdAttribute` to the project with the id `3867c5c2-50b2-4e1a-a53b-c6488418344c`, you must also manually set the same value in the project `<UserSecretsId>` tag.

In fact if you do not add the tag to `.csproj` when you use `Manage User Secrets` in VS (or init secrets by `dotnet` CLI), a new attribute is created for you with a different value (suppose `1234`). And VS and the CLI will work on this secret. But as stated before the runtime will read from the folder with your id.

So when you open the secrets from VS or work with the CLI, then `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\1234\secrets.json` is used, but at runtime the file will be read from `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\3867c5c2-50b2-4e1a-a53b-c6488418344c\secrets.json`.